# Edit methods from frameworks

Tags: macos, cocoa, frameworks, mac-frameworks

I want to implement the Identity Picker sheet from the Collaboration.framewwork but I want to remove some functions (Add User & Address Book). Is that possible? If yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Objective-C API has no means of doing it.  Usually, when Apple omits some functionality, they have a good reason for doing it.  In this case, the identity picker is for picking identities for ACLs.  Why would you want to restrict the user's ability to select whatever identities he or she wants?  At least that's Apple's (possible) thinking.

If you want to restrict the choice to actual users, you'll probably need to create your own sheet and populate it by using the core services methods.